# Custom Generator in OpenApiGenerator Gradle plugin

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi generator plugin and it's working as expected, but I'd like to extend the generator class and modify its behaviour but I'm not sure how to go on about doing that.

It's a java 8 spring boot project

This is my current setup:

```
import org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask

plugins {
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '6.3.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "io.github.openfeign:feign-core:$feignVersion"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5"
}

def openApiConfig = {
    generatorName = "java"
    apiFilesConstrainedTo = [""]
    modelFilesConstrainedTo = [""]
    supportingFilesConstrainedTo = []
    outputDir = "$projectDir".toString()
    templateDir = "$rootDir/api/src/main/resources/codegen/templates"
    invokerPackage = "com.support"
    skipValidateSpec = true
}

task generateApiClient(type: GenerateTask) {
    configure openApiConfig
    remoteInputSpec = "http://localhost:9903/v3/api-docs.yaml"
    apiPackage = "api"
    modelPackage = "model"
    configOptions = [
            library          : "feign",
            dateLibrary      : "java8",
            title            : "Some API",
            useTags          : "true",
            serializableModel: "true",
    ]
}
```